# RegEx non-capturing group issue

Tags: javascript, regex

Why following return `["vddv"]` instead of ["dd"]:

```
"aaavddv".match(/(?:v).*(?:v)/)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?:v) # matches 'v' this is a non-capturing group, not a lookbehind
.*    # matches 'dd'
(?:v) # matches 'v' this is a non-capturing group, not a lookahead
```

Non-capturing groups still participate in the match. Perhaps you want a lookahead/behind? But Javascript does not support lookbehind.

Answer (score 3):

```
"aaavddv".match(/(?:v)(.*)(?:v)/)[1]
```

the whole match is correctly `vddv` but if you want to match only `dd` you need to use a capturing group (and look at element `[1]`)

Answer (score 3):

`/(?:v).*(?:v)/` specifies expression v(number of characters)v